# How do I move every fourth item in a folder?

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

I'm trying to make a script that will move every fourth item in a folder to a destination folder. So far I have:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set originFolder to folder choose folder
    set dest1Folder to folder choose folder
    set dest2Folder to folder choose folder
    set quarter to 1
    repeat with i from 1 to count of items in originFolder
        if quarter is 1 then
            move item i of originFolder to dest1Folder
        else
            move item i of originFolder to dest2Folder

        end if
        if quarter is 4 then
            set quarter to 0
        end if
        set quarter to quarter + 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

but this gives me

```
error "Finder got an error: Expected a reference." number -1727
```

Why isn't this this working and what will work?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems in you script:

Upon setting up the `choose folder` variables you have to put parentheses around `choose folder` in order to force the Finder to convert the [alias](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-SW3) returned by `choose folder` to an [object specifier](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW7):

```
set originFolder to folder (choose folder)
```

The loop that moves the items will terminate with an index out of bounds error because the number of items in the `originFolder` changes upon each iteration through the loop, as items are being moved.

A better solution is to first compute the indexes of the files that should be moved and then have the Finder perform the move operation in one step:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set originFolder to folder (choose folder)
    set destFolder to folder (choose folder)
    set indexes to {}
    repeat with i from 4 to (count of items in originFolder) by 4
        copy i to end of indexes
    end repeat
    move (every item of originFolder whose index is in indexes) to destFolder
end tell
```